# How can I make Mono Void get returned in another Mono Void?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

```
Mono<Void> my_function(final String reviewObject){  
  return Mono.fromCallable(
            () -> {
              ReviewDto reviewDto = new ReviewDto();
              
              try {
                objectMapper.updateValue(reviewDto, reviewObject);
              } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                      throw new InvalidPayloadException("Invalid payload");
              }
              return reviewDto;
            }).then();
}
```

when I call my_function it is not invoking (working), what should I do ??

```
Mono<Void> another_function(){
   my_function(reviewObject);
}
```

Comment: `nothing happens until you subscribe` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_subscribe_method_examples

Comment: According to @Toerktumlare you should invoke your method inside of another_function method so: `my_function(reviewObject).suscribe();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mono<Void> another_function(){
   return my_function(reviewObject);
}
```

and let a consumer of your `another_function()` to decide what to do with that returned `Mono<Void>`!

To be precise it is of course a `subscribe()` this or other way to that reactive `Publisher`: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_subscribe_method_examples